# ImageField as optional. How did you solve the problem?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I notice from stackoverflow thread that you finally were able to solve the problem you encounter about Django ImageField.

I was wondering if you could give me a hand as I am desperate to solve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Here is the snippet:

From requirement.txt:

1. asgiref 3.5.2
2. Django              4.1.3
3. djangorestframework 3.13.1
4. Pillow              9.3.0
5. pip                 21.2.4
6. psycopg2            2.9.5
7. pytz                2022.6
8. setuptools          58.1.0
9. sqlparse            0.4.3
10. tzdata              2022.6

MODEL:

```
    class MbrTopupImage(models.Model):

    topupRefNr  = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    topupRefImg = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='usr/topup', default = 'sys_global/images/no_image.png')

    class Meta:
        db_table = "usr_topupimage"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.topupRefNr)
```

SERIALIZERS:

```
  class UserTopupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    topupRefImg = serializers.ImageField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_empty_file=True,)
    class Meta:
        model = MbrTopupImage
        fields =(
                'topupRefNr',
                'topupRefImg',
            )
```

```
VIEWS:
```

```
class usrTopupTransaction(APIView):

def post(self, request):

    newUserTopupTrans = {
        'topupRefNr'      : request.data['topupRefNr'],
        'topupRefImg'     : request.data['topupRefImg'],
        }

    serializersUserTopup = UserTopupSerializer(data = newUserTopupTrans)

    if serializersUserTopup.is_valid():                         
        serializersUserTopup.save()


        postResponse = {'SUCCESS'   : 0, 
                        'MESSAGE'   : 'New Topup Transaction was successful',
                        'ACTION'    : 'Please check your email.',
                        'Topup'     : [serializersUserTopup.data]}
        return JsonResponse(postResponse, status=status.HTTP_200_OK, safe=False)                            

    postResponse = {'SUCCESS' : 1, 
                    'MESSAGE' : 'Wallet Transaction cannot be serialized', 
                    'ACTION'  : 'Check your Topup Input'}
    return JsonResponse(postResponse, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

You make a field optional by setting [**`blank=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank), this should be done in combination with [**`null=True`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#blank) to set the field to `NULL`/`None` in case the field is left empty, so:

```
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: thanks for comment. 
I have edited my preview question to include additional code snippet.
I wonder what have I missed in order to make ImageField as optional field.